# To detect speakers are playable

Tags: microcontroller

In my audio project, speakers are connected to voice chipcorder(ISD3800) and the voice chip is connected to micro controller.
Audio functions well with the setup.

My question is, Is there any way to find my speakers are playable before playing any audio?
Ideas to detect speaker failure before playing any audio...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Put a signal into them?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do it? I guess one idea might be to connect both sides to I/O pins and give it a quick pulse with one configured as an output and the other as an input to check if the speaker is open circuit but they'd be a few caveats depending on what is driving the speaker.

Comment: I do not have direct access to speaker since it is connected with chip corder IC.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to find my speakers are playable before playing any
>   audio?

Try using them as a microphone - normal speakers will produce a decent signal for regular sound waves.

If you can't do that try using another speaker to produce a ping sound (simple short audio burst) and detecting that in the speaker under test.

Comment: I do not have another speaker in my board. I I do have a mic incorporated in my board for capturing the speaker what plays. Here the environmental noise is the factor, since it is affecting my mic output.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have direct access to the speaker - as I suspect you don't since you say its driven by your chipcorder IC, then you could put a small microphone next to the speaker and monitor it with your microcontroller.
While there are certainly other ways to check the operation of a speaker, I think most of the less complex ones will interfere with the playback operation of the chipcorder IC.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I do not have access to the speaker directly. I do have a mic incorporated in my board for capturing the speaker what plays. Here the environmental noise is the factor, since it is affecting my mic output. What sort of test tone should I play? How do I identify my speaker play? Should i do filtering?

Answer (score 0):

What sort of speaker fault are you looking for?  Defective speaker?  Disconnected speaker?

In some public-safety applications, emergency paging speaker systems must be tested automatically on a periodic basis.  One technique used is to have a microphone located close to each speaker and see if it responds when the speaker is driven with an ultrasonic (20 KHz is common) signal.

Comment: The same automatic periodic testing I am looking for. I do have a microphone incorporated in my board for capturing the speaker what plays. Here the environmental noise is the factor, since it is affecting my mic output. How to avoid the noise?